# How to generate wireshark include folder with make install

Tags: linux, makefile, wireshark, configure, wireshark-dissector

I am compiling and installing wireshark-1.9.2 from its source. The configure;make;make install works fine. But, it does not generate any include folder to contain the headers. I can manually copy all headers scattered in wireshark's root folder to the include folder. But it is messy. Is it possible to generate the include folder and put it under /usr/include or /usr/local/include with some built-in script in wireshark?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Write a script, which will take care of this.

Comment: +1 on this problem. It is a known problem: http://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-dev/201112/msg00098.html